RS485 to TTL converter and Modbus RTU slave
I have to send a device to a place to be controlled by Modbus Master. For that, I had to make a kind of gateway using an MCU board and a Modbus library and some converters RS485/TTL and TTL/RS232.
The slave device I use(and have to send) has a custom protocol and has only RS232 port. And I need to send this device to another person who can only use it via Modbus RTU with RS485. So I had to do the following:
Modbus Master RTU ------------ RS485/TTL -- MCU -- TTL/RS232 -- Slave device
So far I tested with a Modbus Master emulator and works fine where the slave device can use some read/write Modbus functions.
My questions are:

I use MCU as protocol translator(between Modbus protocol and my slave device's custom protocol). What parameters I need to know from the Modbus Master user to hardcode into my MCU before sending them the device and converters? They need to tell me what serial communications parameters they use correct? Also they should tell me what slave number I need to set? Are there anything else?

Regarding physical layer I use RS485/TTL converter and I use the following board:



Do I need to know whether they require 120 Ohm termination resistors? And is it possible to tell whether this board already employs such resistors?


Those detais how to communicate at protocol level and how to ask and present the data are not exactly EE questions but something you need to discuss with your client that has the host. But the list you have should be good.

You need to understand what you bought and how to use it. If you did not receive a manual for the adapter, then don't use it. For example, the adapter does have a 120 ohm resistor, but it's not your decision to enable or disable it. Yes, ModBus requires termination, but if your device plugs into an existing bus, it will already be terminated. Do ask from your client.


Also, the diagrams are misleading or incorrect. The board has MAX485 which is a 5V only chip, so you cannot use it with 3.3V supply. Or you can but it does not have to work at all or it might not work properly and it may cause problems.
The board has automatic transmit enable based on data, but you are not given any parameters what is the delay between start of data to transmit enable, and what is the timeout for transmit disable. If you don't know these you can't put a random surplus device bought from shady online shop to an industrial bus that needs to work properly.
Also the grounding diagram is a bit misleading. Usually you earth the bus common from one place only, and simply connect the bus common ground with other devices without earthing it. You need to know what you can do and what you cannot do to the bus, it might be incorrect for your device to earth it and cause a ground loop.
